# Fetching the values with Element Tree

Tags: python, elementtree, xml.etree

I would like to fetch some values for a particular component. For example i would like to fetch only 2 values from the below output (i.e Component --> name: paristrain and Stat --> TimeoutValue: value). I was trying to do this with xpath but i am not able to get the desired output. Can you please help me in this.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open('rejexstats.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.iter():
    print node.tag, node.attrib
```

This prints:

```
Statistics {}
{http://www.rejex.com/stats}Server {'start': '2013-01-22T22:30:13.583', 'product': 'rejex', 'end': '2013-01-23T09:39:45.249', 'startup': '2013-01-22T22:30:13.583', 'name': 'localhost'}
{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Component {'subtype': 'Thread', 'type': 'Supplier', 'name': 'paristrain'}
{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Stat {'type': 'entry', 'name': 'TimeoutValue', 'value': '120'}
{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Stat {'type': 'entry', 'name': 'PendingRequests', 'value': '0'}
{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Stat {'type': 'entry', 'name': 'Session|0|SupplierTimeout', 'value': '0'}
{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Stat {'type': 'entry', 'name': 'Session|0|Errors', 'value': '0'}
{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Stat {'type': 'entry', 'name': 'Session|3|SupplierTimeout', 'value': '0'}
{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Stat {'type': 'entry', 'name': 'ApplyRulesErrors', 'value': '0'}
```

XML File

```
<Statistics>
    <Server end="2013-02-14T07:06:35.533" name="localhost" product="regex" start="2013-02-13T22:30:12.982" startup="2013-02-13T22:30:12.982">
        <Component name="paristrain" subtype="Thread" type="Supplier">
            <Stat name="TimeoutValue" type="entry" value="120"/>
            <Stat name="PendingRequests" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="Session|0|SupplierTimeout" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="Session|0|Errors" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="Session|3|SupplierTimeout" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="ApplyRulesErrors" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="LateResponses" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="CacheTries" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="Session|4|Errors" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="MaxActiveThreads" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="MaxPendingQueueSize" type="entry" value="10"/>
            <Stat name="ValidResponses" type="entry" value="0"/>
            <Stat name="TranslateResponses" type="entry" value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the full namespace in your XPath query:

```
for component in tree.iterfind('{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Component'):
    print component.attrib['name']
```

Alternatively, you can use an explicit namespace mapping, one that maps a prefix (you choose) to namespace URI:

```
nsmap = {'rej': 'http://www.rejex.com/statistics`}

for stat in tree.iterfind('rej:Stat', namespaces=nsmap):
    print stat.attrib['value']
```

The `rej` prefix is looked up in whatever you pass in as `namespaces`, then transformed to the same XPath query given in the first example.

You can expand on the `{namespace}` xpath qualifier to find more complex matches:

```
tree.find(
    "{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Component[@name='paristrain']/"
    "{http://www.rejex.com/statistics}Stat[@name='TimeoutValue']")
```

should return the `Stat` element that has the attribute `name="TimeoutValue"` whose parent is a `Component` element with a `name="paristrain"` attribute, for example.

Comment: The thing is in my xml file there are so many component. I am only interested in getting the values of component paristrain and its TimeoutValue: Value.

Comment: @fear_matrix: You can create a XPath expression for that using the namespace prefixes.

Comment: @fear_matrix: Untested example XPath expression added. You didn't include any sample XML, so it's hard to test this for you.

Comment: i have mentioned the xml file above

Comment: @fear_matrix: You left off the `xmlns` namespaces. In this case, those are important.